# PHP & mySQL: When exactly to use htmlentities?

Tags: php, mysql

**PLATFORM:**
PHP & mySQL

For my experimentation purposes, I have tried out few of the XSS injections myself on my own website. Consider this situation where I have my form textarea input. As this is a textarea, I am able to enter text and all sorts of (English) characters. Here are my observations:

A). If I apply only strip_tags and mysql_real_escape_string and do not use htmlentities on my input just before inserting the data into the database, **the query is breaking** and I am hit with an error that shows my table structure, due to the abnormal termination.

B). If I am applying strip_tags, mysql_real_escape_string and htmlentities on my input just before inserting the data into the database, **the query is NOT breaking** and I am able to  successfully able to insert data from the textarea into my database.

So I do understand that htmentities must be used at all costs but unsure when exactly it should be used. With the above in mind, I would like to know:

1. When exactly htmlentities should be used? Should it be used just before inserting the data into DB or somehow get the data into DB and then apply htmlentities when I am trying to show the data from the DB?
2. If I follow the method described in point B) above (which I believe is the most obvious and efficient solution in my case), do I still need to apply htmlentities when I am trying to show the data from the DB? If so, why? If not, why not? I ask this because it's really confusing for me after I have gone through the post at: http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/dec/google-xss-example
3. Then there is this one more PHP function called: **html_entity_decode**. Can I use that to show my data from DB (after following my procedure as indicated in point B) as htmlentities was applied on my input? Which one should I prefer from: html_entity_decode and htmlentities and when?

**PREVIEW PAGE:**

I thought it might help to add some more specific details of a specific situation here. Consider that there is a 'Preview' page. Now when I submit the input from a textarea, the Preview page receives the input and shows it html and at the same time, a hidden input collects this input. When the submit button on the Preview button is hit, then the data from the hidden input is POST'ed to a new page and that page inserts the data contained in the hidden input, into the DB. If I do not apply htmlentities when the form is initially submitted (but apply only strip_tags and mysql_real_escape_string) and there's a malicious input in the textarea, the hidden input is broken and the last few characters of the hidden input visibly seen as  `" />` on the page, which is undesirable. So keeping this in mind, I need to do something to preserve the integrity of the hidden input properly on the Preview page and yet collect the data in the hidden input so that it does not break it. How do I go about this? Apologize for the delay in posting this info.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a tip: Most of the time, you shouldn't use htmlentities, but htmlspecialchars. htmlentities converts a ton of characters, while htmlspecialchars only converts those that MUST be converted.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Thanks for the tip. The form accepts all the input that you can possible key in using a US based keyboard. So I had this idea that using htmlentities will make it more safer, just in case someone tries to manually copy and paste some weird characters from some other website or their own system locally. So I opted to use htmlentities. What do you think?

Comment: There's no point. Yes, weird characters could look... well, weird on your site. But you're not avoiding that by using htmlentities, because the entities are just a different way of representing the same character. They don't have any special meaning in HTML, so there's no advantage in translating them - the end result will look the same, it'll just use more bytes to look that way.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thanks much & appreciate for explaining the same.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's the general rule of thumb.

> Escape variables at the **last possible moment**.

You want your variables to be clean representations of the data. That is, if you are trying to store the last name of someone named "O'Brien", then you definitely *don't* want these:

```
O&#39;Brien
O\'Brien
```

.. because, well, that's not his name: there's no ampersands or slashes in it. When you take that variable and output it in a particular context (eg: insert into an SQL query, or print to a HTML page), *that* is when you modify it.

```
$name = "O'Brien";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people "
     . "WHERE lastname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "'";

$html = "<div>Last Name: " . htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES) . "</div>";
```

You never want to have `htmlentities`-encoded strings stored in your database. What happens when you want to generate a CSV or PDF, or anything which *isn't* HTML?

Keep the data clean, and only escape for the specific context of the moment.

Comment: Curious, if there is an item that you do not allow user to use any html, so you save something as non-html text into mysql, do you still need to use htmlentities() when showing it?

Comment: define non-html text? Some thing would consider this to be HTML: `<b>foo</b>`. They'd also consider this HTML: `x<y and y>z`. If you don't want the user to enter HTML, then just don't treat anything they type as HTML - that is, save it into the database verbatim and htmlentities it when echoing to the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my original post to include the info that might be useful to throw some more light on the situation. Kindly refer to it and post your reply. Thanks.

Comment: @nickf I understand your point, but even the popular phpBB forum stores htmlentites-encoded strings in the database.

Answer (score 5):

In essence, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` prior to database insertion (to prevent SQL injection) and then `htmlentities`, etc. at the point of output.

You'll also want to apply sanity checking to all user input to ensure (for example) that numerical values are really numeric, etc. Functions such as [is_int](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), [is_float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php), etc. are useful at this point. (See the [variable handling functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php) section of the PHP manual for more information on these functions and other similar ones.)

Comment: @middaparka Thanks. You are right. But I was trying to make sure that I can be safe of the CSS/XSS attacks. The textarea accepts all kinds of input, numeric, characters, etc. In short, it accepts all the input that you can possible key in using a US based keyboard. So is_int, etc. are not of much help as other kind of inputs are also allowed. I even edited my original post to include more specific info. Kindly refer to it and post your reply as applicable. Thanks much.

Answer (score 5):

1. Only before you are printing value(no matter from DB or from $_GET/$_POST) into HTML. htmlentities  have nothing to do with database.
2. B is overkill. You should mysql_real_escape_string before inserting to DB, and htmlentities before printing to HTML. You don't need to strip tags, after htmlentities tags will be displayed on screen as < b r / >  e.t.c

Theoretically you may do htmlentities before inserting to DB, but this might make further data processing harder, if you would need original text.

```
3. See above
```

Comment: In my opinion you should not use htmlentities before inserting to the DB. You are not preserving the original data if you do that

Comment: Yes, I am saying just the same thing. But if one really want that, it would not pose additional security risk, just a little retard.

Comment: @d03boy :Thank you both for your replies. I edited my original post to include the info that might be useful to throw some more light on the situation. Kindly refer to it and post your reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this before and learned two important things:

If you're getting values from $_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST and plan to add to DB, use mysql_real_escape_string function to sanitize the values. Do not encode them with htmlentities.

Why not just encode them with htmlentities and put them in database? Well, here's the thing - the goal is to make data as meaningful and clean as possible and when you encode the data with htmlentities like Jeff's Dog becomes Jeff&quot;s Dog ... that will cause the context of data to lose its meaning. And if you decide to implement REST servcies and you fetch that string from DB and put it in JSON - it'll come up like Jeff&quot;s Dog which isn't pretty. You'd have to add another function to decode as well.

Suppose you want to search for "Jeff's Dog" using SQL "select * from table where field='Jeff\'s Dog'", you won't find it since "Jeff's Dog" does not match "Jeff&quot;s Dog." Bad, eh?

To output alphanumeric strings (from CHAR type) to a webpage, use htmlentities - ALWAYS!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree with you. I have been using mysql_real_escape_string ever since our friends suggested it. So what do you suggest we use, htmlentities or htmlspecialchars to output alphanumeric strings (from CHAR, VARCHAR type) to a webpage?