# HTML entities in my database. Search with zero results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, non-ascii-characters

I have a trouble with my laravel application, and I don't have idea of what is the problem...

I write in my database spanish words like: `"Camión"` which contains accents, but when I go to `phpmyadmin` I see `"Cami&oacute;n"`.

Due to this, when I use the next sql query:

```
select * from table where name like '%Camión%'
```

I get zero rows. The same if I use:

```
select * from table where name like '%Camion%'
```

I use `utf8_spanish_ci` collate.

can someone help me with that, please?

**I don't know why I store html entities in my database.How I can know? I think I do nothing special...**

Comment: Hmmm... according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077576/php-mysql-when-exactly-to-use-htmlentities we should not store input as htmlentities. However, that is how I normally do it, too. Not sure how to solve this as there is no MySQL decode function.

Comment: Maybe this could help you [http://xaviesteve.com/1223/issues-with-accents-and-strange-characters-in-php-mysql-solved/](http://xaviesteve.com/1223/issues-with-accents-and-strange-characters-in-php-mysql-solved/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store html entities in the database.  Those entities are intended for use in HTML only, in order to prevent cross site scripting attacks amongst other things.  Use htmlentites when outputting to a HTML page via PHP.

Having said this, make sure you properly parametrize your database queries when using user-inputted data in order to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I don't know why I store html entities in my database.How I can know? I think I do nothing special...

Comment: I use e() method... Thanks I dont knew that :) Do you know any filter xss in laravel?

Comment: And please, add your comment to your answer

Comment: e() is basically a shortcut for htmlentities() in laravel.  Use it when you are outputting data to the html page, *after* you have retrieved that data from the database.  Don't use e() when inserting data into the database.